# >4GB of memory for 32 bit application running on 64-bit Solaris (Very Large Memory)

Tags: memory, memory-management, solaris

Both MS Windows and Oracle Linux allows 32bit applications to use >4GB of Memory. Windows method is AWE: [Address Windowing Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Windowing_Extensions) and Linux's method is [Very Large Memory](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32009/appi_vlm.htm).

How it works: 32-bit application can't directly address > 4 GB of Virtual memory; but 64-bit OS can and 4GB of memory is too small to some applications. So, VLM and AWE allow application to reserve huge amount of memory from 64bit OS (or even from 32bit OS with AWE). 32-bit application can't address this memory directly, but it can ask OS to setup mapping of some part of huge memory into first 4GB (into 32-bit virtual space), then this memory can be accessed, modified; then it is unmapped back (with OS request).

Question is: Is there something like VLM or AWE in Solaris OS (version 10 or 11; x86_64 or sparc64)?

Comment: AWE works on a 32-bit OS too. It's about fiddling virtual to physical mappings rather than leveraging the larger virtual address space of the host OS.

Comment: yes, I know and i said this in Q "from 32bit OS with AWE". The question is does Solaris have something like AWE/VLM?

Comment: @osgx, Please let me know if you have found the answer on an outside source.

Comment: @Anders, if VLM works via creating a ramdisk (tmpfs/shmfs) and then create a lot medium sized files or single huge file, and then uses mmap/munmap of needed portions of data.. Then I think, solaris is able to do the same. Not more 4GB at any single time, but many GB of RAM is accessible in mmap-ed "windows" (regions). Software should be updated to support this, of course.

Comment: @osgx, you can always mmap an ordinary huge file and rely on buffering to keep the used parts in memory. I cannot check right now, but I'm pretty sure Solaris has tmpfs, so you can choose to map files in a tmpfs.

Comment: @chill, but if the file is on ramdisk, i can be sure that i will work with memory (especially if swapping is disabled for this tmpfs)

Comment: @osgx: Sorry, I should have read more carefully. My key point, though, was that it's about virtual-physical address mapping (Linux's ramfs maps to physical memory), not user-kernel address mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no library I'm aware of but implementing it would be quite straightforward under Solaris (and all Unix/Unix like OSes supporting tmpfs and mmap).

Just create a file the size you want (eg: 16 GiB) in /tmp (assuming /tmp is on tmpfs, the default configuration) and have the process(es) mapping various areas of this file to access memory at the wanted offsets.

Should you really want to access physical memory and not virtual one, you can use Solaris ramdisk support (ramdiskadm) instead of tmpfs.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris supports PAE (Physical Address Extension), but Googling around doesn't paint a pretty picture. There is very little information available, and most of it is dire warnings that a bunch of third-party drivers won't work with it.

Comment: The question is not about PAE, it is about 32bit program on 64bit OS. 64bit OS need no PAE to use >4GB of mem, because it can directly address 2^64 (virtually) or 2^36-2^40 (physically). But 32 bit program can't address > 4GB of mem and even PAE can't do anything with this. (PAE didn't change `sizeof(void*)`; it only allow OS to map higher physical memory into lower 4GB of memory which is virtual memory or addressable by program memory)

Comment: Anyway, "virtual-physical address mapping" is managed by OS, and VLM is OS/userspace collaborate technique.

Comment: @osgx: You're right. However, both VLM and AWE rely on PAE. If you can't get PAE going on Solaris, you won't be able to address more than 4 GB.

Comment: No. VLM don't rely on PAE. 64-bit OS (this is my case) don't rely on PAE. PAE is not only >4GB access method even for 32 bit OS: the other is PSE36: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSE-36